# TSQL GROUP and average past 3 years

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

i would like to find the result of grouping by year and their average amount for past 3 years round to 2 decimal places, using tsql

```
    data

    Year amount
    2017 100
    2017 200
    2016 300
    2016 100
    2015 200
    2015 200
    2014 100
    2013 100

    expected result
    year amount
    2017 183.33
    2016 166.66
    2015 133.33
    2014 100 
    2013 100
```

Comment: And what have your tried?

Comment: Strange expected results.

You seem to have missed off what you have tried so far.

Comment: How come the value of 2015 is 133.33? Shouldn't it be 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**`avg() over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to get the average over the last three years, from a subquery that averages the amount for that year.

```
select 
    year
  , amount = avg(amount) over (order by year rows 2 preceding)
from (
  select year, amount = avg(convert(decimal(19,2),amount))
  from t
  group by year
  ) as s
order by year desc
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SUUP93797

returns:

```
+------+------------+
| year |   amount   |
+------+------------+
| 2017 | 183.333333 |
| 2016 | 166.666666 |
| 2015 | 133.333333 |
| 2014 | 100.000000 |
| 2013 | 100.000000 |
+------+------------+
```